# nested form_for singular resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested

I have a singular nested resource like so:

```
  map.resources :bookings, :member => { :rate => :post } do |booking|
    booking.resource :review
  end
```

Giving me these routes:

```
   new_booking_review GET    /bookings/:booking_id/review/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"new"}
  edit_booking_review GET    /bookings/:booking_id/review/edit(.:format)     {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"edit"}
       booking_review GET    /bookings/:booking_id/review(.:format)          {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"show"}
                      PUT    /bookings/:booking_id/review(.:format)          {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"update"}
                      DELETE /bookings/:booking_id/review(.:format)          {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"destroy"}
                      POST   /bookings/:booking_id/review(.:format)          {:controller=>"reviews", :action=>"create"}
```

I tried this:

```
<% form_for [@booking, @review] do |f| %>
```

Which returned this error:

```
undefined method `booking_reviews_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x10572b888>
```

With my reviews controller

```
  def new
    @review = Review.new
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:booking_id])
  end
```

But this works... if I list the URL explicitly...

```
<% form_for :review, :url => booking_review_path(@booking) do |f| %>
```

It's not a big deal... but i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `form_for` assumes all nested resources are *plural* resources. Fixing `form_for` would be the *correct* thing to do (and I urge you to [submit a bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/)), but in the mean time, you can fake it:

```
# in app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def booking_reviews_path(*args)
    booking_review_path(*args)
  end

end
```

You can't use `alias_method` because the method `booking_review_path` doesn't exist in that module, but this is essentially the same thing.

Comment: It looks like there's already a bug noted: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3675-form_for-doesnt-work-with-new-singleton-nested-resource