# Routing Nested Resource With Has One Relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each project can have a single page:

```
resources :project do
    resource :page
  end

  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :page
  end

  class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
  end


  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @page = @project.build_page
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
      end
    end

    def create
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @page = @project.build_page(params[:page_id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @page.save
          format.html { redirect_to @page, :notice => 'Page was successfully created.' }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
        end
      end
    end
```

But when I go to save a page, I not only get a routing error, but it doesn't actually save to the db.

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/projects/2/pages"
```

My form action looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@job, @page]) do |f| %>
```

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on? I kind of pieced all of this together from other SO posts, but the more I change a line here or there, I feel like I'm getting further from a working solution. For example, if I change the form action to be:

```
<%= form_for @page, url: job_page_path(@job) do |f| %>
```

Everything magically works, but then the edit action is still broken. What basic concept am I butchering?

Thanks!
--Mark

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo:

```
 resource :page
```

should be

```
 resources :page
```

(notice the s)

`resource` (singular) is actually quite a different method that builds a different set of routes. See [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources/resource) for more info.

**UPDATE / ERRATUM**

sorry, i've read your question too fast. you should take a look at [Ruby on rails: singular resource and form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736759/ruby-on-rails-singular-resource-and-form-for) - it seems that `form_for` does not know how to properly handle singular resources.

Someone here on SO suggests a quick fix for this : [nested form_for singular resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261827/nested-form-for-singular-resource)